# gitlab push commit gif - gif contains errors

Tags: git, gitlab, gif

I'm trying to commit and push animated gifs to gitlab, but all the gifs end up corrupt?

When comitting/pushing other types of files, there is no issue. Only gifs are corrupt: I cannot open them when I use gitlabs' file browser.

I'm pushing from a windows machine to linux machine.

What am I doing wrong?

This is one of the failing gifs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRlWm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It was a git configuration issue: all image types where configured as binary, except *.gif.

The solution was to update .gitattributes:

```
*.gif binary
```